# Text of a editText is disappears when Focus changed

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

My layout parent is RelativeLayout. Inside that relativelayout i have 3 LinearLayouts. The 3rd LinearLayout is having two edittexts, which is in bottom of the screen.

The problem is when we click on that edittexts keyboard is coming, I m able to enter some text on that edittext. then i am dismiss the keyboard. after that i have one button whenever user press that button i m disabling these two edittexts that time text will disappears from the edittexts.

This problem is in some devices only, i faced this problem in Samsung SM-T210R, OS version 4.4.2

This is my edittext code.

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etInvEmail"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:typeface="serif" />
```

Please give me some solution.

Comment: Try to do a editText.getText().toString());. Tell me what you get.

Comment: I m getting text even though it is disappears.

Comment: In the xml set the textColor of the EditText to #000.

Comment: text is appearing when i m clicking again for re enter some more text

Comment: Please paste you complete layout xml, its something related to color either text or background color of layout. Everything else seems to working fine as per your explanation.

Comment: it is working if I place the bottom LinearLayout to top. The problem is occurred only if I place that part in bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can by using a selector:

drawable/my_custom_edittext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#FF0000"/>
    <item android:color="#0000FF"/>
</selector>
```

layout/main_activity.xml:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="your text"
    android:textColor="@drawable/my_custom_edittext" />
```

It should solve your problem.

Comment: in my code I m not setting any colors for edittext text.

Comment: Apply some text color and then test. If still not then paste your complete xml please.